# How to find Records between startDate and endDate - Nodejs, mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There are 4 records in my database.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"6200b15e91f762376cd43ac3"},"startDate":{"$date":"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},"endDate":{"$date":"2021-01-28T18:29:59.059Z"},"__v":0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6200b15e91f762376cd43ac4"},"startDate":{"$date":"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},"endDate":{"$date":"2021-01-23T18:29:59.059Z"},"__v":0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6200b15e91f762376cd43ac5"},"startDate":{"$date":"2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"},"endDate":{"$date":"2021-01-28T18:29:59.059Z"},"__v":0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6200b15e91f762376cd43ac6"},"startDate":{"$date":"2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"},"endDate":{"$date":"2021-01-25T18:29:59.059Z"},"__v":0}
```

My UI looks like this:

[image]

My mongodb query is as follows: (what I have tried)

```
data.find({
                    "$or": [
                      {"startDate": {"$gte": startDate}},
                      {"endDate": {"$lte": endDate}}
                    ]
                  });
```

When is search using the query above, I get only 1 record, That is: `{"_id":{"$oid":"6200b15e91f762376cd43ac3"},"startDate":{"$date":"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},"endDate":{"$date":"2021-01-28T18:29:59.059Z"},"__v":0}` instead of all 4.

While sending from UI, I convert it is:
`req.query`:

```
dateStart: '2021-01-01',
dateEnd: '2021-01-28',
```

And then convert it to `new Date()` format:

```
let startDate = new Date(req.query.dateStart); 
let endDate = new Date(req.query.dateEnd);
```

I don't know what wrong I am going in the query. Need Help! Thank you!

Comment: shouldnt it be and statement since it has to satisfy gte startdate 'and' lte enddate

Comment: Try converting the dates to ISO format. That should help.

Comment: also when you create new Date of '2021-01-28' it will give `"2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z"` so you will not get 1st and 3rd result

Comment: @cmgchess shouldn't it be what? I did not get you

Comment: @Gobind Deep Singh I tried converting it to ISO format. That does not work. Would that change the format of what is in db and what I send to backend query?

Comment: Adding `$and` gives me empty array. It does not give me any result. Using `$or` I get just one outcome instead of 4

Comment: Isn't `2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z` what is saved in db? How will that differ? @cmgchess

Answer (score 0):

With $and seems to work as expected :

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      startDate: {
        $gte: {
       "$date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
       }
       },
      endDate: {
        $lte: {
       "$date": "2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z"
       }
      }
     }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pUQAjCiXAE1)

Comment: This does not seem to work as well. when I code it in mongo playground it work fine. But i dont understand why it does not work on my machine

Comment: Is it something to do with the date format? coz it is not at all working

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting all 4 records to be returned, for the end date you should be querying using the time before the date `2021-01-28` ends which is `2021-01-28T23:59:59.999Z` instead of when the date starts which is `2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z`.

[Here's a resource on timestamps format](https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Sources/04Reference-Information-for-Sources/Timestamps%2C-Time-Zones%2C-Time-Ranges%2C-and-Date-Formats).

So a query like this would work:

```
db.collection.find({
  startDate: {
    $gte: {
      "$date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  endDate: {
    $lte: {
      "$date": "2021-01-28T23:59:59.999Z"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: No actually. This does not work for me